# Access VBA Runtime error 3070: ...does not recognize Assgnrst.MemberID as a valid fieldname or expression

Tags: ms-access, vba7

I get this error with the FindFirst statement. Code is below.

```
    If Assgnrst.CompID <> 0 Then
        ComID = Assgnrst!CompID!Value
        Debug.Print Assgnrst.MemberID, ComID
        FindFirststr = "Assgnrst.MemberID = " & ComID & ""
        Debug.Print FindFirststr
        Assgnrst.FindFirst (FindFirststr) -- The error happens on this line
```

The results of Debug.Print:

```
 MemberID & ComID: 1049          1304 
 FindFirststr: Assgnrst!MemberID = 1304
```

Other fields in Assgnrst are being recognized. MemberID is a field in Assgnrst (as shown in the first Debug.Print). What could be the issue?

Comment: What happens if you build the string like this? `FindFirststr = "MemberID = " & ComID & ""`

Comment: `Assgnrst` is not part of the field name so don't use that as prefix in search criteria. I don't understand logic. Why would you search for MemberID = CompID?

Comment: @Hansup - I was positive I tried that, but when I changed the code it worked. Thank you.